# Comes before/after; is before/after

Tags: word-usage

I was flipping through channels looking for Nat Geo. But then I reached channel 570. But Nat Geo is channel no. 550.
If another person has to tell this to the person flipping through the channels, what sounds natural:

> Nat Geo is before this channel.
>
> Nat Geo comes before this channel.

---

> This channel is after Nat Geo.
>
> This channel comes after Nat Geo.

Do the sentences sound better with or without that "come"?

And what about:

> I guess I've skipped Nat Geo.
>
> I guess I've missed Nat Geo.

Do these two sentences sound natural to you?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the "is before" sentence for a conversational context.

As far as how I would actually say this, and what I would consider idiomatic:

> (I think) You've gone past it - Nat Geo is 550.
>
> Keep going - Nat Geo is 550.

The bracketed "I think" is optional; I feel it would be used in a context where you'd want to be a bit more polite, e.g., if you don't know the person very well.

Comment: Thank you:) Your sentence is of course more idiomatic than mine. But do you think that "is before" or "is after" might be used? (If not in a conversation,then in description or maybe in a conversation like: **You've gone past it. It is before this channel**. [If you yourself aren't sure of the exact channel number]) And can it be "**It is somewhere before this channel**". I feel that it does not sound natural. Am I right in thinking so?

Comment: Yes, in that context, "before" and "after" would absolutely make sense and be idiomatic. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use "is" instead of "comes". Using "comes" is okay, but it presupposes that someone is flipping through the channels from lowest to highest. That is often not the case, since you could also change the channel by typing in the number or by going from higher to lower. That being said, either is really fine, and what I've said about "comes" here is certainly not the only interpretation.

As for your second question, I don't have a strong preference for *missed* or *skipped*. I would ever so slightly prefer *skipped* in this situation since it seems slightly less formal, maybe because it implies a bit more culpability.

Also, I wouldn't abbreviate National Geographic to Nat Geo in writing or speech, but that might just be me.